# how to install opencv in ubuntu karmic koala

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

anyone know how to get a working install of opencv in karmic? I've tried pretty much every way i can find in a google search and none seem to work..

Comment: Could you mention what error you are facing ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the [Open Source Computer Vision library, OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)?

The 1.0 version is available in Karmic's `universe` repositories.  You'll need to make sure that repository is enabled in your package manager.  According to [this post](http://wiki.nuigroup.com/Installing_OpenCV_on_Ubuntu), you want to run this command to install all the library packages, or edit the list to leave off packages you don't want:

```
sudo apt-get install libcv1 libcvaux1 libcvaux-dev libcv-dev libhighgui1 libhighgui-dev opencv-doc python-opencv
```

If you want the 2.0 version, you'll need to grab the OpenCV 2.0 source [from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.0/) and build it yourself.  See the [OpenCV wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and [2.0 Release Notes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0.Readme.Please.txt/view) for details.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a guide of how I got it to work, might be use to you -> http://alexsleat.com/2009/12/02/howto-install-opencv-in-ubuntu-karmic-9-10/

Answer (score 0):

To install OpenCV using the terminal on Ubuntu:

```
$ su -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get install libavformat-dev
# apt-get install x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
# apt-get install libcv2.3 libcvaux2.3 libhighgui2.3 python-opencv opencv-doc libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev
```

OpenCV should be installed in /usr/local/ Installation Directory

You may also want to compile and view examples

```
$ cp -r /usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/examples .
$ cd examples
$ cd c
$ sh build_all.sh
```

Source: http://namhuy.net/1205/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu.html